# Is it thread safe to reset and copy shared_ptr simultaneously?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, shared-ptr

[Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety) describes shared pointer's behavior when accessing it from multiple threads simultaneously. Particularly they give some examples:

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42));

//--- Example 1 ---

// thread A
shared_ptr<int> p2(p); // reads p

// thread B
shared_ptr<int> p3(p); // OK, multiple reads are safe

//--- Example 2 ---

// thread A
p.reset(new int(1912)); // writes p

// thread B
p2.reset(); // OK, writes p2

//--- Example 3 ---

// thread A
p = p3; // reads p3, writes p

// thread B
p3.reset(); // writes p3; undefined, simultaneous read/write
...
```

But they do not say (or I cannot see) what will happen if the same `shared_ptr` object is written and read at the same time. Say:

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42));

//--- My Example ---

// thread A
p.reset(new int(1912));

// thread B
shared_ptr<int> p1 = p;
```

So my question is whether the last example is OK or not?

NOTE: Boost's third example explains that it is not safe to read and write the same object in parallel. But in their example they assign `p3` to `p`, which is a copy of `p3`. So it is not clear to me whether the safety of that example depends on the fact that `p3` gets assigned to its copy or whether something else is unsafe.

Comment: Your example is exactly the same as theirs - one thread reads `p`, one thread writes `p`, so it can't be safe.

Comment: @molbdnilo on their example they write to `p` (the copy of `p3`) and `p3`, so I thought that unsafety can be depended on that fact.

Comment: No, it's irrelevant. The examples are just to illustrate _some_ examples, not every possible example. The text at the top is what you need to read for the definitive answer and it's very clear.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Now, after your answer it became clear to me, thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> But they does not say (or I cannot see) what will happen if the same shared_ptr object will be written and read at the same time.

Yes they do:

> A `shared_ptr` instance can be "read" (accessed using only const operations) simultaneously by multiple threads. Different `shared_ptr` instances can be "written to" (accessed using mutable operations such as `operator=` or `reset`) simultaneously by multiple threads (even when these instances are copies, and share the same reference count underneath.)
>
> **Any other simultaneous accesses result in undefined behavior.**

(emphasis mine)

Seems pretty clear to me.

> So my question is whether the last example OK or not?

No, because what you are doing is not reading simultaneously from a single instance, nor writing to separate instances. You are simultaneously reading and writing a single instance. That's a data race, and undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Now that we have C++11 (and 14/17), you may use the atomic shared pointer classes to atomically handle shared pointers in your threads.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic

Simply put, if you may end up modifying a shared pointer, you should use the atomic functions everywhere (all reads and all writes.) Then your threads should not crash because of the shared pointer.

Comment: But currently it is (deprecated in C++20) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic

Comment: @Alex, do you know the reason why it's being deprecated?

Comment: C++20 suggests `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>;` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2  Since `std::shared_ptr<T>` is not Trivial copyable, so it seems `T` in `std::atomic<T>;` can be not Trivial copyable in C++20, or did `std::shared_ptr<T>` become Trivial copyable.